# Returning NaN on a groupedby dataframe filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

So can someone please shed light on why I'm getting 'NaN' for the following:

Here is my dataframe:

```
  df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                          'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'jack'],
                      'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                       'two', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'four']})
```

THen I groupby column 'A'

```
df3 = df2.groupby('A')
for A, group in df3:
    print (A)
    print (group)
```

Result:

```
bar
     A      B
1  bar    one
3  bar  three
5  bar    two
foo
     A      B
0  foo    one
2  foo    two
4  foo    two
6  foo    one
7  foo  three
jack
      A     B
8  jack  four
```

All good so far, so what I want to return is the grouped collection where the column 'B' contains either 'one' or 'two':

```
df4 = df3.apply (lambda x: (x[x['B'] == 'one']) | (x[x['B'] == 'two']))
```

The result I get is:

```
        A   B
A           
bar 1   NaN NaN
    5   NaN NaN
foo 0   NaN NaN
    2   NaN NaN
    4   NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not filter out beforehand?

```
pd.concat({k : g for k, g in df2[df2.B.isin(['one', 'two'])].groupby('A')})

         A    B
bar 1  bar  one
    5  bar  two
foo 0  foo  one
    2  foo  two
    4  foo  two
    6  foo  one
```

If you're just looking to get separate groups without concatenating them together, stop at

```
groups = {k : g for k, g in df2[df2.B.isin(['one', 'two'])].groupby('A')}
```

Where each group is accessible by `groups['bar']` or `groups['foo']`.

Comment: but what's wrong with the code itself for it to return "NaN" ??

Comment: @Sammy7 it was just wrong. You were subsetting two dataframes and then doing an | OR operation which made no sense. Fixing your code would've made it `df3.apply(lambda x: x[(x['B'] == 'one') | (x['B'] == 'two')])` which is still worse than the other answer which isn't as good as just filtering once outside.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `groupby` and `apply`

```
df2.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x[x['B'].isin(['one','two'])])

         A    B
A              
bar 1  bar  one
    5  bar  two
foo 0  foo  one
    2  foo  two
    4  foo  two
    6  foo  one
```

Comment: True, but filtering per group turns out to be slower than filtering for the whole.

Comment: @coldspeed ah, didn't know that. I find it easier to write though. i think it's fine for small data but not the best practice. Thanks (: